# Nhibernate - Generated by sequence with oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, sequence

I am using nhibernate and I have crossed an issue, I want to know how the nhibernate - GeneratedBy Sequence works.
Is it generating an id from the sequence when I'm trying to save no matter what? for example, if I have an entity which I mapped it to generate the id from the sequence, and I set the id to a different value than 0, will it generate the id from the sequence? or just save as the given id?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, try it, and you will probably see it will generate an id from the sequence. I do not know of any id [generator](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator) allowing to explicitly set the id except the `assigned` generator.

You may be interested in the [Creating a custom id generator](http://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/various/creating-a-custom-id-generator-for-nhibernate.html) tutorial if you actually need some kind of hybrid sequence/assigned generator. It should help you write your own. But its semantic will be tricky: how will you ensure an assigned id will not be issued later on by the sequence itself?

Comment: Thanks mate, I have tried it, and it always generated the sequence no matter wjat